# How to process large files on gae

Tags: python, xml, google-app-engine, large-files

I want my app to download an XML file and process it daily. The XML file comes in a ~100MB zip file - ~1GB when extracted. The processed output is less than 1MB.

I noticed the URL fetch (and urllib) response size quota is 32MB:
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/overview.html#Quotas_and_Limits

Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use [Blobstores](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview.html)

Comment: I don't need to store the XML files - just download and process them. Problem is the urlfetch/urllib download size limit.